# onclick on button outlook email should open using Javascript or using anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, email, xslt, href

trying to use html but the email content part have variables also .. like have to display his/her contact number or registration number which I cannot hard code in email template , so if I use JavaScript and try to do with text area
how can I use variables inside it ?

```
<textarea id="myText" style="display:none">

function sendMail(){
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
        + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
        + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
        + "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('myText').value);`

    window.location.href = link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try Anchor Tag Direct Open Outllook**

```
<a href="mailto:name1@rapidtables.com?cc=name2@rapidtables.com&bcc=name3@rapidtables.com
&amp;subject=The%20subject%20of%20the%20email
&amp;body=The%20body%20of%20the%20email">
Send mail with cc, bcc, subject and body</a>
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mL26Lvew/)

**Using Javscript**

```
function Setemail(mailto,cc,bcc,subjcet,body,Title)
{
 var email='<a href="mailto:'+mailto+'?cc='+mailto+'&bcc='+bcc+'&amp;subject='+subjcet'&amp;body='+body+'">'
+Title+'</a>';
}
```